# How to Join two Armatures without losing constraints in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I want to join two separate armature objects, But when I join two armatures using "Ctrl + J" then the bones with constraints not working properly.Also I renamed all the bones differently.

Is there any way to join to armatures without losing constraints?

[image: These are two armatures]

[image: Before join]

[image: After Join]

Comment: could you please share the 2 armatures and tell what bone doesn't work anymore after you've joined? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I have added images

Comment: thanks, but maybe share the armatures (not the rest) because I'm not sure the pictures will help to understand, we don't know anything about the bones, their constraints, etc...

Comment: Sorry for inconvenient, but I found the answer and it is that after joining two hooks assigned objects are disappeared so i manually attached those back, and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of this problem:
I used curve with hooks to make SplineIK and when I join two armatures then all hooks are gone, So I manually had to assign that hooks again and now It is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

All constraints look for an armature and a bone. If you merged the "B" armature into the "A" armature, probably some constraint are looking for an "X" bone which was in the "B" armature, but now it is into the "A" armature. If all bones names are different, it should be enough to change all constraints armature target from "B" to "A".